# Testing .where queries in rspec-rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm quite new to Rspec testing in Rails and I'm trying to test the following:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  def host_details
    query ||= User.where(id: self.user_id)
  end

  def hosting_company
    company = host_details.first.company
  end
end
```

I have the following spec but I'm not sure exactly what I'm supposed to be expecting back for the results of the `host_details` method. I'm using FactoryGirl.

```
describe "gets information about the host of an event" do
  before(:each) do
    @event = build(:event)
  end

  context "host_details" do
    it "querys the event data and finds the associated user" do

    end
  end

  context "hosting_company" do
    it "gets the company that is hosting the event" do
      expect(@event.hosting_company).to eq "Attnd"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: The query itself looks like an implementation detail. I'd probably shorten the test to `it "returns the associated user"`.

Comment: BTW, `query ||=` is superfluous, because `query` is a _local variable_. You have to use an _instance variable_ in order to memoize the result, i.e. `@query ||=`. Furthermore you are only storing the query and not the query's (much more expensive) result. Keep in mind that _"premature optimization is the root of all evil"_